# Oniguruma regex conditional group capture

Tags: regex, oniguruma

I am attempting to capture the word `function` using Oniguruma regex (for VSCode syntax highlighting) into 2 different groups depending on if `::` are the preceding characters. As far as I know Oniguruma does not support conditionals, hence I thought I could capture the regex result into group 1 if the characters are not present and into group 2 if they are

Currently, I have the following:

```regex
(?>::\s*\b(function)\b)|\b(function)\b
```

Some text to test the code on:

```
  integer function fun_with_func_space(     function    )
    integer, intent(inout) :: function
  end function fun_with_func_space
```

#### Intended regex match

Given the text above group `$1` should

```
finds 1st and 2nd "function" in 'integer function fun_with_func_space(     function    )'
finds no match in 'integer, intent(inout) :: function'
finds "function" in 'end function fun_with_func_space'
```

group $2 on the other hand should

```
finds no match in 'integer function fun_with_func_space(     function    )'
find "function" in 'integer function fun_with_func_space(     function    )'
finds no match in 'end function fun_with_func_space'
```

As far as I understand the following should mean:
"Capture and exit into group 2 the word `function` if preceded by :: else capture `function` in group 1."
and according to regex101.com it should work: https://regex101.com/r/VtgeTD/1, yet my syntax highlighting is still failing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CarySwoveland sure I will edit, but it is a simple if-else-if conditional that I am seeking to implement `if ::\s*\bfunction\b capture in $1 else if \bfunction\b capture in $2`

Comment: I might have messed up the order of what goes into group `$1` and `$2` (not sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a look behind:

```
(?<=::|:: )\b(function)\b|\b(function)\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/TmtSXUG16qgKPr).

Or use a non-capturing group:

```
(?:::\s*)(function)\b|\b(function)\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/gv1Znt7G3zmuLg).

Comment: Your first example does the trick. I somehow didn't think to add the last bit `|\b(function)\b`. Moreover, as far as I can tell in VSCode, look-behinds can be of non-fixed width so `(?<=::|:: )` can be swapped for `(?<=::\s*)`

Comment: @Cary it doesn't work without it. The goal is to capture `function` in group `1` if preceded by `:: `, group `2` otherwise.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah! Good call. It was a carry over from an earlier version: I deleted it (and updated the demo link too.

Comment: I am coming back to note that using non-fixed width look behinds come at a considerable cost (specifically for VS Code syntax highlighting)